# Append data to the end of an existing Excelsheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I want to append a pandas DataFrame to an existing Excel Sheet `mysheet1`.
I developed a minimal reproducible example below that creates two df (df1 and df2).
The exmple saves the first df (df1) with the pandas.to_excel function to simulate an existing excel file.

The problem with the example below is, that it doesn't append to the end of the existing 
sheet `mysheet1` but rather creates a second sheet called `mysheet11`.

How can I manage that the content of df2 is instead appended to the original sheet `mysheet1`

**Edit1**
The excel file I want to read in has multiple sheets that should not be overwritten but preserved

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

def create_dt_range(start_date,end_date):
    mytimeindex = []
    timecounter = start_date
    for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).total_seconds() / 60 / 60)):
        mytimeindex.append(timecounter)
        timecounter = timecounter + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
    return mytimeindex

# Generating Datetimeindexes
df1_index = create_dt_range(datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1,0,0,0),datetime.datetime(2011,2, 2,0,0,0))
df2_index = create_dt_range(datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 1,0,0,0),datetime.datetime(2011,4, 2,0,0,0))

# Combining randomnumbers and datetime index to a df
df1_data = np.random.randint(1,100,len(df1_index))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1_data, index=df1_index,columns=['Foo'])
df2_data = np.random.randint(-10,0,len(df2_index))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2_data, index=df2_index,columns=['Foo'])

file = "Test.xlsx"
# Simulate an existing file - create text.xlsx
df1.to_excel(file, sheet_name="mysheet1")

with pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="mysheet1")
```

**Edit2**
Solution that preserves other sheets and appends as intended to the End of `mysheet1`, however with 1 empty row between original sheet data and newly appended df2.
**Edit3**
Filtering for `[None]` with and if in the final for-loop solved the empty row. Thanks to all.

```
# ... Continuation of previous code
# Solution provided by emiljoj
from openpyxl import Workbook #reading/loading workbooks
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows #appending dataframes to rows

wb=load_workbook(file, read_only=False)
ws_mysheet1 = wb["mysheet1"]

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df2, header=False):
    if not r == [None]:
        ws_mysheet1.append(r)
    else:
        print("Skipped empty row")

wb.save(file)
wb.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach would be to try editing the excel sheet with the module openpyxl, firstly opening the workbook, identifying the relevant sheet and then appending the dataframe

```
from openpyxl import Workbook #reading/loading workbooks
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows #appending dataframes to rows

wb=load_workbook('your_workbook_path.xlsx', read_only=False)
ws_mysheet1 = wb["mysheet1"]

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df_to_append, index=False, header=False):
       ws_mysheet1.append(r)
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, with some minimal changes. After checking the docs I added a `wb.save(file)` and `wb.close()` at the end [link]https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html

Comment: I also removed the `index = False` argument. This appends df2 to the `file = Text.xlsx` as intended. There is only a small thing left to fix, it inserts an empty row after the original `mysheet1`

Comment: Added an condifitional `if not r == [None]:` to fix the empty row. Worked perfect

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could concatenate the file and the data frame in Pandas, then save to Excel?

```
from pandas import read_excel, concat

df1 = read_excel('Input_file.xlsx')

# df2 defined previously

df = concat([df1, df2])

with pd.ExcelWriter('Output_file.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="mysheet1")
```

Comment: Worked as a charm when I first tried it. The problem is, if there are other sheets in that excel file they are deleted. I want to preserve existing other sheets. I edited the OP to clarify

Comment: pd.ExcelWriter('Output_file.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a',if_sheet_exists='replace') would solve the deletion of other sheets if this method is to be used in the future.